# The etymology of 便当 in Chinese

Tags: etymology, word, history, loanwords

The following excerpt is from [the top answer on 知乎](https://www.zhihu.com/question/26290171?sort=created):

> 丈夫每天吃自己做的**便当**（没错，是他自己做的，不是他妻子做的）她吃大餐，去一次美容院就能花4.2万。看表情就知道，这位太太毫无愧疚之心，可能还觉得自己萌萌哒。两人摊牌后，妻子没有道歉，而是要求丈夫以后更努力工作赚钱。最后以这男人跳下站台自杀，妻子改嫁结束。

The 便当 here means a bento-box. However, since it is clear that "bento" in English is a loanword from Japanese, I feel that it is a loanword from Japanese in Mandarin as well, not a word that had been incorporated into Japanese.

However, the Japanese word is 弁当, not 便当. So my question is:

- Is my assumption correct that it is a loanword from Japanese?
- If that is true, then why is it called 便当 in Chinese? And when did it start to be called as such?

Comment: Baidu answer: 最早源于南宋时期的俗语“便当”，意思是“便利的东西、方便、顺利”。传入日本后，曾以“便道”、“辨道”、“辨当”等当字（当て字）表记。 “便当”一词后来反传入中国是源于日语“弁当”（音:bentou）。更多已经简化翻译成Bento了,在大陆大部分地区习惯称为“盒饭”，即盒装餐食。在台湾地区一般称为 便当,通常用于午餐、外卖、工作餐等场合。“便当”与“盒饭”在用法上有细微差异，“盒饭”一词更倾向于简单粗糙的饭食，如“日式便当”一词，就很少被说成“日式盒饭”。https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%BE%BF%E5%BD%93/6032932?fr=aladdin

Comment: @dan Can you make it as an answer, possibly in English and possibly in more elaboration?

Comment: I made a rough one below fyr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to make a rough translation here:

> 便当， originated from the Southern Song Dynasty, meaning "convenient
>   things, convenient, smooth".
>
> When introduced into Japan, it became “便道”、“辨道”、“辨当”.
>
> Later, when the term “便当” was transplanted back to China from Japan,
>   it's referenced to 弁当(bentou/bento).
>
> The term 盒饭, (that is 盒装餐食), is used in mainland, while
>   便当 is usually used in Taiwan.
>
> However, there is a nuance between 盒饭 and 便当. 便当 is more delicate than
>   盒饭.  盒饭 is usually just simple and normal food.